# fullCalendar className to multiple eventSources

Tags: json, calendar, fullcalendar, classname

I am trying to setup my fullCalendar event sources.
instead of pulling all of my events through 1 source, I would like to use multiple sources (ie: google, and local json)

Here is what I have so far ***(In short)***:

```
eventSources: 
[

//CA HOLIDAYS
$.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.canadian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic', { className: 'holiday' }), 

//General events
'events.php?a=getAllCalendarEvents'

],
```

The problem that I am having is, I can get the gCalFeed to have a className, but not exactly sure how to get my other source to have a className...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the only other way is to individually set a 'className' property for each one of your events objects.

it would be nice to set a source's className as one high-level property. please feel free to request this feature (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/support/)

Comment: That's too bad, will totally have to have that in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `className` to the whole `eventSource`

```
eventSources: 
[

//CA HOLIDAYS
$.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.canadian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic', { className: 'holiday' }), 

//General events
{
  events: 'events.php?a=getAllCalendarEvents',  
  className: 'GeneralEvents'
}

],
```